# How can i access variables inside of firebase .ref closures and use them outside

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I declared a variable inside a firebase function i would like to use it outside of the function. I already declare the variable outside of the function and then set it inside of the firebase function but Im still not able to retrieve how can i process this.

```
let ref = firebasehelper.firebaseURL()
    var userDict = [String:String]()
    var name:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.childByAppendingPath("backend/posts").queryOrderedByChild("jobOfferFromId").queryEqualToValue(ref.authData.uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in


     self.name =  snapshot.value["jobDescribe"] as! String


 // work greate in here
        print(self.name)


    })

    // does not work outside of the Firebase function I want to access the data out here
        print(self.name)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `func` inside the class then place the `func` inside the class this will allow you to set that variable inside the funciton

Answer (score 3):

that is because you do the print(self.name) before you have the data back from Firebase.

You could put the query in viewWillAppear and then do the print(self.name) in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad. best would be to actually use the closure and only trigger the next step (print) once the data is back, so by putting a reference to a function (with the print(self.name) or any other use you have for the data) outside viewDidLoad.